# setAccuracy vs setHorizontalAccuracy

Tags: android, android-location

[setAccuracy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#setAccuracy%28int%29)

> Indicates the desired accuracy for latitude and longitude. Accuracy may be ACCURACY_FINE if desired location is fine, else it can be ACCURACY_COARSE. More accurate location may consume more power and may take longer.

[setHorizontalAccuracy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#setHorizontalAccuracy%28int%29)

> Indicates the desired horizontal accuracy (latitude and longitude). Accuracy may be ACCURACY_LOW, ACCURACY_MEDIUM, ACCURACY_HIGH or NO_REQUIREMENT. More accurate location may consume more power and may take longer.

Another example of the pristine android docs. So what is the difference ? Notice they take different constants - is it possible/desirable to specify both with some combination of constants ?

Comment: Asked at GG : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/S5XE8B7juY8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/location/java/android/location/Criteria.java) is rather clear.

```
/**
 * Indicates the desired horizontal accuracy (latitude and longitude).
 * Accuracy may be {@link #ACCURACY_LOW}, {@link #ACCURACY_MEDIUM},
 * {@link #ACCURACY_HIGH} or {@link #NO_REQUIREMENT}.
 * More accurate location may consume more power and may take longer.
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if accuracy is not one of the supported constants
 */
public void setHorizontalAccuracy(int accuracy) {
    if (accuracy < NO_REQUIREMENT || accuracy > ACCURACY_HIGH) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("accuracy=" + accuracy);
    }
    mHorizontalAccuracy = accuracy;
}

/**
 * Returns a constant indicating the desired horizontal accuracy (latitude and longitude).
 * Accuracy may be {@link #ACCURACY_LOW}, {@link #ACCURACY_MEDIUM},
 * {@link #ACCURACY_HIGH} or {@link #NO_REQUIREMENT}.
 */
public int getHorizontalAccuracy() {
    return mHorizontalAccuracy;
}

/**
 * Indicates the desired accuracy for latitude and longitude. Accuracy
 * may be {@link #ACCURACY_FINE} if desired location
 * is fine, else it can be {@link #ACCURACY_COARSE}.
 * More accurate location may consume more power and may take longer.
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if accuracy is not one of the supported constants
 */
public void setAccuracy(int accuracy) {
    if (accuracy < NO_REQUIREMENT || accuracy > ACCURACY_COARSE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("accuracy=" + accuracy);
    }
    if (accuracy == ACCURACY_FINE) {
        mHorizontalAccuracy = ACCURACY_HIGH;
    } else {
        mHorizontalAccuracy = ACCURACY_LOW;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a constant indicating desired accuracy of location
 * Accuracy may be {@link #ACCURACY_FINE} if desired location
 * is fine, else it can be {@link #ACCURACY_COARSE}.
 */
public int getAccuracy() {
    if (mHorizontalAccuracy >= ACCURACY_HIGH) {
        return ACCURACY_FINE;
    } else {
        return ACCURACY_COARSE;
    }
}
```

> So what is the difference ? Notice they take different constants - is it possible/desirable to specify both with some combination of constants ?

Well it makes no difference - `setAccuracy()` just sets `mHorizontalAccuracy` to either `ACCURACY_HIGH` or `ACCURACY_LOW` - if you want `ACCURACY_MEDIUM` or `NO_REQUIREMENT` you must call `setHorizontalAccuracy()`.

So accuracy internally is just the "horizontal accuracy". Now if anyone knows why they needed both I would accept his/her answer - closing for now.